# How to export txt file from print

Tags: python

```
posts = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('whiteLink')
for post in posts:
print(post.text)
saveFile = open('Names.txt','w')
saveFile.write(post)
saveFile.close()
```

I want to save posts to txt file in the same folder as py file.
I'm scraping info from web and trying to put it in txt file.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to rearrange the function calls. Before the for loop, you can create the file. For each post in posts, print to the screen and write the same data to the file. One thing to keep in mind is that not all strings have a newline character ("\n" below). What this means is that if you just write post.text with adding the character, it will all print on a single line in the document.

```
posts = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('whiteLink')
saveFile = open('Names.txt','w')
for post in posts:
    print(post.text)
    saveFile.write(post.text + "\n")
saveFile.close()
```

Another similar (and frankly better) solution is to use a context manager. What this does is make sure that the file closes automatically when it exits the statement. This may be better if any errors are encountered in the loop

```
posts = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('whiteLink')
with open('Names.txt','w') as saveFile:
    for post in posts:
        print(post.text)
        saveFile.write(post.text + "\n")
```

If the above doesn't work (As you mentioned in the comment), you could store a string and print out or write the whole string at once.

```
posts = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('whiteLink')
output = ("{}\n"*len(posts)).format([post.text for post in posts])
print(output)
with open('Names.txt','w') as saveFile:
    saveFile.write(output)
```

Comment: It makes file but its empty on console i see parsed data

Comment: I'm wondering if you have to convert post.text into a string, or it is stored as a string in the object. maybe try str(post.text)?

Comment: Try making a constant list of posts = ["one","two","three"] or something like that and see if that outputs anything or not. I'm wondering if it is post.text might be causing problem and print() is doing something different to interpret it compared to file.write()